# mod_rewrite based on current HTTP_HOST and HTTP_REFERER

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-referer, http-host

Is it possible to make such check with htaccess mod_rewrite - 
If a referer domain is example.com and current host is www.example.com 
then redirect the user to example.com domain.
The meaning is to keep the user at first visiting domain (www or non-www).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See, if this works for you.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond ${HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond ${HTTP_REFERER} ^http://domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```